# Pythonic way to remove directories from a file listing

Tags: python

I can think of easy ways to accomplish this, but what is the most pythonic way?   I get a file listing for os.listdir, and some may be directories.

I could check through each one in a loop and check if os.isdir returns false, then remove it from the list.  What is a pythonic way to write this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[x for x in os.listdir(...) if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(..., x))]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
files = filter(lambda f: os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f)), os.listdir(path))
```

OR

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, f))]
```

**Edited**: removed bug per Ignacio's answer (added in calls to os.path.join)

Comment: but -1 for non-functional programming (I missed path.join, as Ignacio suggested). Should look more like: filter(lambda f: os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,f)), os.listdir(path))