# List only files in a directory?

Tags: python

Is there a way to list the files (not directories) in a directory with Python? I know I could use `os.listdir` and a loop of `os.path.isfile()`s, but if there's something simpler (like a function `os.path.listfilesindir` or something), it would probably be better.

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6664205)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This is [a simple generator expression](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw):

```
files = (file for file in os.listdir(path) 
         if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, file)))
for file in files: # You could shorten this to one line, but it runs on a bit.
    ...
```

Or you could make a generator function if it suited you better:

```
def files(path):
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, file)):
            yield file
```

Then simply:

```
for file in files(path):
    ...
```

Comment: your forgot to add join between dirname and filename

Comment: @ayvango That's just a different behaviour - there was no call for giving a full path in the question, and this works as-is in a well-defined way.

Comment: os.listdir returns basenames of the files, and you may stat them directly by basename only if your current directory matches given path

Comment: @ayvango I see what you mean - I was thinking about the returned values, not the check - you are indeed correct. I will update it.

Comment: based on above answer, you could do: `files = list(filter(lambda x: os.path.isfile(x), os.listdir(path)))`

Comment: @Ganesh K You need to join the path and filename for the `isfile()` call to work, there is no reason to make a list, and a generator expression is preferable to filter/lambda.

Comment: This is not recursive, it will only get the files directly inside path.

Comment: @bugmenot123 Just directly in the directory was what the question asked for.

Answer (score 11):

```
files = next(os.walk('..'))[2]
```

Comment: What's next? Single line answer cought my attention but I can't understand it.

Comment: maybe  next(os.walk(os.getcwd()))[2] better?

Answer (score 10):

Since Python 3.6 you can use glob with a recursive option "**". Note that glob will give you all files and directories, so you can keep only the ones that are files

```
files = glob.glob(join(in_path, "**/*"), recursive=True)
files = [f for f in files if os.path.isfile(f)]
```

Answer (score 9):

Using pathlib in Windows as follow:

> files = (x for x in Path("your_path") if x.is_file())

Generates error:

> TypeError: 'WindowsPath' object is not iterable

You should rather use [Path.iterdir()](https://pathlib.readthedocs.org/en/pep428/#pathlib.Path.iterdir)

```
filePath = Path("your_path")
if filePath.is_dir():
    files = list(x for x in filePath.iterdir() if x.is_file())
```

Answer (score 7):

For the special case of working with files in the current directory, you could do it as a simple one-liner list comprehension:

```
[f for f in os.listdir(os.curdir) if os.path.isfile(f)]
```

Otherwise in the more general case, directory paths & filenames have to be joined:

```
dirpath = '~/path_to_dir_of_interest'
files = [f for f in os.listdir(dirpath) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirpath, f))]
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try [pathlib](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib), which has a lot of other useful stuff too.

Pathlib is an object-oriented library for interacting with filesystem paths. To get the files in the current directory, one can do:

```
from pathlib import *
files = (x for x in Path(".") if x.is_file())
for file in files:
    print(str(file), "is a file!")
```

This is, in my opinion, more Pythonic than using `os.path`.

See also: [PEP 428](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0428/).

Comment: One common advice is to avoid that kind of import. That is, rather just import what you use, which in your case would just be `from pathlib import Path`.

Comment: While `pathlib` is great, I would argue it depends on the script at hand - if it only deals with files a couple of times, depending on `pathlib` might be overkill.

Answer (score 2):

Using `pathlib`, the shortest way to list only files is:

```
[x for x in Path("your_path").iterdir() if x.is_file()]
```

with depth support if need be.

Comment: And how would one specify the depth?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Python 3, you could use [pathlib](https://pathlib.readthedocs.io/en/pep428/#).

**But**, you have to know that if you use the `is_dir()` method as :

```
from pathlib import *

#p is directory path
#files is list of files in the form of path type

files=[x for x in p.iterdir() if x.is_file()]
```

empty files will be skipped by `.iterdir()`

The solution I found is:

```
from pathlib import *

#p is directory path

#listing all directory's content, even empty files
contents=list(p.glob("*"))

#if element in contents isn't a folder, it's a file
#is_dir() even works for empty folders...!

files=[x for x in contents if not x.is_dir()]
```