# Renaming all the files in a folder is renaming the sub folders too

Tags: python-3.x

When try to rename the files in a specific folder, the program code renames 
all the sub folders too. Is there a way to fix it?

```
        dname = input("\nenter the path\t")
        if os.path.isdir(dname):
            dst = input("\nenter new file name: \t")
            n = 1
            for i in os.listdir(dname):
                if not os.path.isdir(i):
                    mystr = ".txt"
                    src = os.path.join(dname, i)
                    dd = dst + str(n) + mystr
                    dd = os.path.join(dname, dd)
                    os.rename(src, dd)
                    n += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours "isdirectory" (`os.path.isdir(i)`) check doesn't seem to work.

You can precompile the list of files present in the directory using the below code,

```
files = (file for file in os.listdir (dname)
           if os.path.isfile ( os.path.join ( dname, file) ))
```

And then directly iterate over the files, like,

```
  for i in files:
    mystr = ".txt"
    src = os.path.join(dname, i)
    dd = dst + str(n) + mystr
    dd = os.path.join(dname, dd)
    os.rename(src, dd)
    n += 1
```

You can also have a look at this answer, which lists all the ways in which you can list files in a given directory.

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14176179/10164003

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems below the line isn't working for you.

> os.path.isdir(i)

Try out creating the full path before checking :

> os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dname, i)):