# Filter ntScanDirInterator to only files

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to shrink a list down to just files with Python. `os.scandir` gives files and folders. `os.path.isfile` returns `True` if an entry is a file and `False` if it's a directory.

I want `new_files` to only be the files (only those objects that return `True`).

I'm struggling with the syntax for this!

```
import os
new_items = os.scandir('C:/temp/logs')
new_files = [item in new_items if os.path.isfile(item) == True]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List only files in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176166/list-only-files-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 0):

```
new_files = [item for item in new_items if os.path.isfile(item) == True]
```

Reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comprehensions-in-python/